# How can I specifiy the .spec file in PyInstaller

Tags: python, compilation, pyinstaller

How can I specifiy the *.spec* file while compiling my *.py* file with **PyInstaller** using the **--onefile** and **--noconsole** options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\main.py --onefile  --noconsole main.spec
```

Answer (score 8):

**PyInstaller** will generate a `.spec` file. You can run it first against your one file app and then for future runs reference your edited `.spec` file

- Use one file app:

  `pyinstaller main.py`

  *Note: this will overwrite `main.spec` so don't use this on future runs*
- Use `.spec` file:

  `pyinstaller main.spec`